# Clone a Mercurial project using Git?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git interoperability with a Mercurial Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883452/git-interoperability-with-a-mercurial-repository)

I'm using Git for all of my projects. Now I would like to clone a project that is using Mercurial.

Is there some kind of Mercurial <-> Git bridge or something that I can use?

Comment: You could use the solution outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883452/git-interoperability-with-a-mercurial-repository

Comment: @MauvisLedford: I don't want to convert/export it. I want to clone it so that I can receive updates.

Comment: @jgauffin, same approach, although getting constant updates from the origin would be hard.

Comment: @MauvisLedford: No its not the same. A clone makes it easier to merge my changes with the ones from the origin. Doing an export equals manual merging, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preface**

1. Git can't pull of push to Mercurial repo
2. Mercurial (with hg-git) works with git in both direction

**Resume**

You have to use one more hg-repo in the middle maybe [mentioned by obmarg way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089221/960558), or [my (untested) way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7916447/960558)